# Convert from C/C++/Java source code to unicode with python 3

Tags: python, unicode

I have some raw data that I want to convert to its characters in unicode.
Example:

```
"<http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/data/id/911805> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "RDF description of \u0394HMOTIKH \u0395NOTHTA \u0398\u0399\u039D\u0391\u039B\u0399\u039F\u03A5" <http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/data/id/911805> ."
```

I have used the classic:

```
with open("dump_final.nq", encoding="utf-8") as f:
```

And what I should get is all the characters starting with \u converted to its unicode characters.

I get the same as the beggining, no conversion is made.

Thank you.

Comment: Alberto, 
I would like you to explain better what is happening as your question is not clear. What have the title to do with the body? Why C/C++/Java when you talk about raw data? 

Please take some time to explain better what you mean, removing all unnecessary information. Write an example of original raw data and what you expect to obtain from it.

Answer (score 0):

I refer raw data because it is some data that I want to transform. It is composed of some URIs and some of them contain characters that are in C/C++/Java source code. For example if I have a string like "\u03A5" it should be transform into an Upsilon symbol, as it is shown here: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03a5/index.htm
Thank you.
Kind regards.